# Jquery - select2 dropdown disabled when cloning a table row

Tags: jquery-select2

I have a table with four select2 dropdown lists.
When I clone the row to duplicate it, the dropdown lists of the new row are disabled, I can't click on them, what do I have to add in my code in order to activate them.

The HTML table :

```
<table id="fla_inf" width="100%">
<tbody>
<tr>
<th class="tab_header" colspan="6">Flavors and Additives</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="tab_header_nam">Flavor Brand</th>
<th class="tab_header_nam">Flavor Name</th>
<th class="tab_header_nam">Dropper type</th>
<th class="tab_header_nam">Quantity Unit</th>
<th class="tab_header_nam">Quantity</th>
<th class="tab_header_nam">Add/Remove row</th>
</tr>
<tr class="flavors">
<td>[brand_list]</td>
<td><select id="arome0" class="select2-select"></select></td>
<td><select id="dropper0" class="select2-select">
<option selected="selected" value="type1">type 1</option>
<option value="type2">type 2-3</option>
</select></td>
<td><select id="qtyunit0" class="select2-select">
<option value="ml">ml</option>
<option value="drops">drops</option>
<option selected="selected" value="perc">%</option>
</select></td>
<td><input id="quantity0" class="quantity" type="number" /></td>
<td><input class="addline" src="http://example.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/add.png" type="image" /><input class="remline" src="http://example.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/delete.png" type="image" /></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

and the jquery code :

```
// Add row to the table by cloning existing row
 $(document).on('click', '.addline', function(){

    var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var allTrs = $tr.closest('table').find('tr');
    var lastTr = allTrs[allTrs.length-1];
    var $clone = $(lastTr).clone();
    $clone.find('td').each(function(){
        var el = $(this).find(':first-child');
        var id = el.attr('id') || null;
        if(id) {
            var i = id.substr(id.length-1);
            var prefix = id.substr(0, (id.length-1));
            el.attr('id', prefix+(+i+1));
            el.attr('name', prefix+(+i+1));
        }
    });
    $tr.closest('tbody').append($clone);
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I try to avoid cloning elements for this kind of reason. An alternative to cloning is to use a template for the html.

If you want to continue cloning, you could un-instrument the Select2 controls in the original row before you clone it, and re-instrument them afterwards.

You un-instrument the Select2 controls with the `.select2('destroy')` function.

```
$(document).on('click', '.addline', function () {
    var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var $lastTr = $tr.closest('table').find('tr:last');

    $lastTr.find('.select2-select').select2('destroy'); // Un-instrument original row

    var $clone = $lastTr.clone(); // Clone row

    $clone.find('td').each(function() { // Alter cloned ids
        // ...
    });

    $tr.closest('tbody').append($clone); // Append clone

    $lastTr.find('.select2-select').select2(); // Re-instrument original row

    $clone.find('.select2-select').select2(); // Instrument clone
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Lauecqz/)

Comment: Thanks for you're answer, I'll test it. The reason for cloning is I need the content of the dropdown lists to avoid unnecessary queries to the database. If I destroy the list, will it loose it's content ?

Comment: @user3515709 - "destroy" will just un-instrument the select, it will not remove the options. You can see that in the jsfiddle. I understand about your reason for cloning.

Comment: cannot believe i found the exact problem i was having. works great. thanks