# Select2 control is Disabled on Dynamic Table

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-select2

I have a table in which I used Select2 Control which works fine with elements loaded from database.

**HTML**

```
                           <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                                <tr ng-repeat="lineItem in lineItems">
                                    <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="lineItem.selected" /></td>
                                    <td>{{lineItem.rowNumber}}</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <select id="drpItem" class="form-control select2 select2-hidden-accessible" ng-model="lineItem.item" ng-options="item as item.itemCode for item in vm.items" name="ItemCode" style="width: 100%;">
                                            <option value="0">Select Item</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </td>

                                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="lineItem.item.itemName" required /></td>
                                    <td><input type="number" class="form-control" ng-model="lineItem.quantity" required /></td>
                                    <td><input type="number" class="form-control" ng-model="lineItem.item.unitPrice" required /></td>
                                    <td><span ng-model="lineItem.lineTotal">{{getLineTotal(lineItem)}}</span></td>
                                </tr>
                           </table>
```

The following Javascript initializes it just fine.

```
        $(function () {
            $('.select2').select2();
        });
```

I have a button that dynamically adds rows to the grid in AngularJS

```
      $scope.addNew = function (lineItem) {
            $scope.lineItems.push({
                'rowNumber': $scope.rowNum++,
                'item.id': '',
                ['item.itemName']: '',
                'quantity': 1,
                ['item.unitPrice']: ''
            });
        };
```

My problem here is when I click to add a new row, the row is added but Select2 control becomes disabled. I have tried to get past this issue all day but to no avail. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What does the vm.items array look like?

Comment: @CameronRodriguez It's an array that gets populated from database. That's what fills up the control. Note that before a new row is added, the control works fine with the items inside the dropdown.

Comment: What do you mean your select becomes disabled? There's no condition on it for it to be disabled. Do you mean it loses its options? What happens to it?

Comment: @CameronRodriguez It just becomes unclickable like a normal control disabled. That's exactly the confusion as I didn't put any condition for that.

Comment: The problem isn't in the code you posted. If you can replicate it in a codepen I can help much better. If you're not able to do that, edit your question to include your full controller

Comment: @CameronRodriguez Let me see if I can replicate it in a fiddle for you. The controller is too much to post on the question.

Comment: @CameronRodriguez While I'm at it, can you take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28518158/jquery-select2-dropdown-disabled-when-cloning-a-table-row . The guy appeared to have a similar problem with me, the only difference is I am not cloning anything. I tried to implement his answer but it didn't work for me. Maybe it could give you a lead.   Many Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140095/discussion-between-cameron-rodriguez-and-kacey-ezerioha).